# Angular - operations on html with directives?

Tags: angular

```js
<ul class="added-elements">
      {{
        <li *ngFor="let element of addedElements">{{element.amount}} {{element.title}}</li>
        ??
        "No element added yet"
      }}
</ul>
```

Is this possible in some way?

I want to check if any li element is made, if not write "No element added yet"

Comment: You mean [something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xs1t2l?file=src/app/app.component.html)? 

Comment: Or you could even write it [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rwv3c4?file=src/app/app.component.html) without modifying the directives.

Comment: uuuh yeah thats great, didnt thought of custom directives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your message in an element, and only show it if there are no elements, so

```
<li *ngIf="addedElements.length == 0">No elems yet"</li>
```

Comment: not really what i asked for, but yeah it works and is probably way better than my idea of adding operation on html elements 

Answer (score 1):

You can check if addedElements has lenght. If not, just render span using ngIf
`<span *ngIf="!addedElements.lenght>No element added yet</span>`

Answer (score 1):

An idea...

```html
 <li *ngIf="elements.length > 0"; else NotElements>

....
           
<ng-template #NotElements>
   <label> Not elements </label>
</ng-template>
```

:)